# Transpose of dynamic data

Tags: sql-server, pivot, transpose

I'm trying to extract the number of sales operations for every month for a number of variable sale centers.
Using the following TSQL...

```
;WITH Months(m) AS
(
    SELECT 1 m
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT m+1 FROM Months WHERE m < 12
)
SELECT  t.Center,m Month, t.Sales FROM Months
CROSS APPLY 
(
    SELECT C.Center, COUNT(1) Sales FROM Operations C
    LEFT JOIN Centers A ON A.Code=C.Center
    WHERE Date BETWEEN '01/'+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),Months.m) + '/2013' AND DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,'01/'+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),Months.m) + '/2013')+1,0))
    GROUP BY C.Center
) t
```

So I get the following output:

```
Center   Month   Sales
-----------------------
A        1       20
B        1       30
A        2       25
B        2       30
....
```

And what I want to end with is:

```
Center   1    2    ...
----------------------
A        20   25   ...
B        30   30   ...
```

I'm studying pivot with xmlpath, but It's so complicated that I can't make it work. Anyone has a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I am missing something with your question but since there are only 12 months in the year, there shouldn't be a reason to use dynamic SQL as you will only ever have 12 columns.

This could easily be accomplished using the following query:

```
select center, 
  [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11], [12]
from
(
  select o.center, month(date) month
  from operations o
  inner join centers c
    on o.center = c.code
  where c.date >= '2013-01-01'
    and c.date <= '2013-12-31'
) d
pivot
(
  count(month)
  for month in ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], 
                [10], [11], [12])
) piv
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5ce9ee/11).

If you want to do this dynamically, then you could use the following:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @startdate datetime,
    @enddate datetime

set @startdate = '2013-01-01'
set @enddate = '2013-12-31'

;WITH Months(m) AS
(
    SELECT 1 m
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT m+1 FROM Months WHERE m < 12
)
select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(m) 
                    from Months
                    group by m
                    order by m
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')


set @query = 'SELECT center, ' + @cols + ' 
            from 
            (
              select o.center, month(date) month
              from operations o
              inner join centers c
                on o.center = c.code
              where c.date >= '''+convert(varchar(10), @startdate, 120)+'''
                and c.date <= '''+convert(varchar(10), @enddate, 120)+'''
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                count(month)
                for month in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '


execute sp_executesql @query;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5ce9ee/19)

Comment: Dear Bluefeet, simply adding the pivot section to the end of my query solved the problem. I was trying for not to write the month numbers in the pivot sentence, as I saw I would like to get semesters or quarts in the future with a parameter. If you modify your answer to correct the selection error on the dates I would mark the as the correct answer. Thanks.

Comment: @Sergio This shows how to get the columns dynamically, I'm not sure what you mean _If you modify your answer to correct the selection error on the dates_.  What error?

Comment: I only meant that your selection does not return the data for every separated month, but for a range.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do it. Why fight Sql Server into something it wasn't meant to do ?

Let your query return data vertically, just like you have now.

Transpose it on the application level.
It will be much easier to write, debug, maintain, and handle special business rules which will undoubtedly pop up.

Also, it will make it easier to paste data into Excel for troubleshooting and pivoting.

Comment: Thanks David for your comment. I see your point, but while developing I prefer to leave the data processing to the database, that it's meant for.
I like the web server (receiver of the data in this case) to take care of serving pages and take on requests and traffic, that it's enough work.
That allows me to abstract the different pages from the data they work on. Ex. Dashboards will have the same code independent of what data they work on.

Comment: Database is meant to return you data.  It is not meant to control your UI level.

Comment: Database is not controlling anything about UI. But It's supposed to return the data required. Nothing more or less.
I've been a Database admin and programmer for more than 15 years and I'm really sure that I haven't been confused in something like this for all those years.

Answer (score 0):

I finally implemented the first suggestion of BlueFeet, with slight changes:

```
;WITH Months(m) AS
(
    SELECT 1 m
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT m+1 FROM Months WHERE m < 12
)
SELECT * FROM Months
CROSS APPLY 
(
    SELECT C.Center, COUNT(1) Sales FROM Operations C
    LEFT JOIN Centers A ON A.Code=C.Center
    WHERE Date BETWEEN '01/'+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),Months.m) + '/2013' AND DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,'01/'+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),Months.m) + '/2013')+1,0))
    GROUP BY C.Center
) t
pivot
(
    max(Sales)
    for m in ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12])
) as PIV
```

What I was looking for it's not to write the month numbers on the pivot statement, so I could only return a quarter, for example. But that makes the work required.
Thanks.